# Скачать динамическую таблицу из браузера в Excel файле

Tags: php, node.js, vue.js, excel

Есть HTML таблица, построенная в браузере через VueJS, ее необходимо скачать в формате Excel. Это должно довольно универсальное решение, которое можно расширить на многие виды таблиц.

Такие варианты не подходят:

- скачать HTML под видом `.xlsx`
- таблица строится по фильтрам в браузере, поэтому серверная генерация через `PHPExcel` не подходит - придется и в браузере через JS фильтровать, и на сервере через PHP, да еще и код построения "ячейка А1, записать ..." поддерживать - а таблиц много, рефакторить все подряд невозможно, только самый минимум изменений
- готовая JS-либа, которая и таблицу строит, и скачивает Excel. Таблица уже построена средствами VueJS, ее возможно менять, но отказаться от VueJS нельзя

Особенность: в таблице есть небольшое декорирование, например, теги `<span>`.

Как это можно сделать наиболее простым путем? Есть такие идеи:

- получаем содержимое `<table>..</table>` в виде строки, которую шлем на сервер, и уже он строит Excel (PHP, NodeJS, еще что-то). Но как?
- какая-то JS-библиотека, которую можно "натравить" на `<table>`

Пример таблицы:

```js
"use strict";

var nsReport = new Vue({
  el: "#js-ns-report",
  data: {
    atLeastOneTender: true,
    items: [{
        skuArticul: "ABB-101",
        _selected: true,
        skuName: "",
        RequestNumber: "-",
        orderNumber: "-",
        specificProduct: "-",
        deliveryPointName: "-",
        deliveryPointAddress: "-",
        tender: "-",
        remainDemand: "-",
        freeStock: "-",
        status: "В процессе"
      },
      {
        skuArticul: "BDN-16",
        _selected: true,
        skuName: "",
        RequestNumber: "-",
        orderNumber: "-",
        specificProduct: "-",
        deliveryPointName: "-",
        deliveryPointAddress: "-",
        tender: "-",
        remainDemand: "-",
        freeStock: "-",
        status: "В процессе"
      },
      {
        skuArticul: "YML-9",
        _selected: true,
        skuName: "",
        RequestNumber: "-",
        orderNumber: "-",
        specificProduct: "-",
        deliveryPointName: "-",
        deliveryPointAddress: "-",
        tender: "-",
        remainDemand: "-",
        freeStock: "-",
        status: "В процессе"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.table {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="js-ns-report">

  <div class="btn btn-primary" @click="atLeastOneTender = !atLeastOneTender">Скрыть/показать колонку</div>
  <div class="btn btn-default">Скачать в Excel</div>

  <table class="table table-bordered ns-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">
          <label for="select-row-all" class="custom-control custom-checkbox" title="Выделить все / снять выделение" style="display: inline-block;">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="select-row-all">
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
     &nbsp;
    </label> Артикул
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2">
          Название
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2">Заявка</th>
        <th rowspan="2">
          Счет
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2">
          Заказная продукция
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2">Грузополучатель</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Адрес доставки</th>
        <th rowspan="2" v-if="atLeastOneTender">
          Тендер
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Остаток</th>
        <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">
          Статус
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>спроса</th>
        <th>свободный</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, idx) in items">
        <td class="nowrap-ellipsis">
          <label :for="'select-row-' + idx" class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: inline-block;">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
      :id="'select-row-' + idx"
      v-model="row._selected">
      &nbsp;
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    </label> {{ row.skuArticul }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ row.skuName }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.RequestNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.orderNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.specificProduct == '1' ? 'Да' : 'Нет' }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.deliveryPointName }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.deliveryPointAddress }}</td>
        <td v-if="atLeastOneTender">{{ row.tender }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.remainDemand }}</td>
        <td>
          {{ row.freeStock }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ row.status }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: Почитайте https://habr.com/ru/post/245233/

Comment: @Дмытрык, там используется либа, я с ней знаком, она строит и таблицу, и Excel. Она не устраивает тем, что ее невозможно скрестить с VueJS.

Comment: @Дмитрий, PHPExcel не подходит, так как таблица строится в браузере, и я об этом упоминул. Иначе мне придется делать логику фильтрации и в браузере в JS, и на сервере в PHP. Этот вариант не устраивает.

Comment: Я тоже пытался решить подобную задачу.... подключал некторое кол-во vue-плагинов... пытался сам делать... однако, никак не получалось создать файл, который бы корректно открывался на MacOs. ... плагин, что я скинул, единственный решил эту задачу..  Найдете другой - сообщите тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел библиотеку [SheetJS](https://sheetjs.com/), вот [демка](https://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html), которая берет DOM элемент `<table ...` и делает `.xlsx`, а вообще заявлено в [документации](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#sheetjs-js-xlsx) множество форматов: `ODS`, `CSV`, ..., причем можно и в обратную сторону `Excel` => `HTML`

Можно прикрутить к любой странице, не обязательно VueJS:

1. Вставляем скрипт `<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>`
2. Добавляем `id` таблице: `id="js-table"`
3. Делаем обработчик нажатия на кнопку `Экспорт`:

```js
var workbook = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById('js-table'));
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'filename.xlsx');
```

Также есть либа [tableexport](https://tableexport.v5.travismclarke.com/#tableexport)

Вот так получилось в моем примере:

```js
"use strict";

var nsReport = new Vue({
  el: "#js-ns-report",
  methods: {
    toExcel: function() {
      var workbook = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById('js-table'));
      XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'filename.xlsx');
    }
  },
  data: {
    atLeastOneTender: true,
    items: [{
        skuArticul: "ABB-101",
        _selected: true,
        skuName: "",
        RequestNumber: "-",
        orderNumber: "-",
        specificProduct: "-",
        deliveryPointName: "-",
        deliveryPointAddress: "-",
        tender: "-",
        remainDemand: "-",
        freeStock: "-",
        status: "В процессе"
      },
      {
        skuArticul: "BDN-16",
        _selected: true,
        skuName: "",
        RequestNumber: "-",
        orderNumber: "-",
        specificProduct: "-",
        deliveryPointName: "-",
        deliveryPointAddress: "-",
        tender: "-",
        remainDemand: "-",
        freeStock: "-",
        status: "В процессе"
      },
      {
        skuArticul: "YML-9",
        _selected: true,
        skuName: "",
        RequestNumber: "-",
        orderNumber: "-",
        specificProduct: "-",
        deliveryPointName: "-",
        deliveryPointAddress: "-",
        tender: "-",
        remainDemand: "-",
        freeStock: "-",
        status: "В процессе"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.table {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="js-ns-report">

  <div class="btn btn-primary" @click="atLeastOneTender = !atLeastOneTender">Скрыть/показать колонку</div>
  <div class="btn btn-default" @click="toExcel">Скачать в Excel</div>

  <table id="js-table" class="table table-bordered ns-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">
          <label for="select-row-all" class="custom-control custom-checkbox" title="Выделить все / снять выделение" style="display: inline-block;">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="select-row-all">
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
     &nbsp;
    </label> Артикул
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2">
          Название
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2">Заявка</th>
        <th rowspan="2">
          Счет
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2">
          Заказная продукция
        </th>
        <th rowspan="2">Грузополучатель</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Адрес доставки</th>
        <th rowspan="2" v-if="atLeastOneTender">
          Тендер
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Остаток</th>
        <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">
          Статус
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>спроса</th>
        <th>свободный</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, idx) in items">
        <td class="nowrap-ellipsis">
          <label :for="'select-row-' + idx" class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: inline-block;">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
      :id="'select-row-' + idx"
      v-model="row._selected">
      &nbsp;
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    </label> {{ row.skuArticul }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ row.skuName }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.RequestNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.orderNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.specificProduct == '1' ? 'Да' : 'Нет' }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.deliveryPointName }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.deliveryPointAddress }}</td>
        <td v-if="atLeastOneTender">{{ row.tender }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.remainDemand }}</td>
        <td>
          {{ row.freeStock }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ row.status }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```