# Экспорт таблицы из сайта в excel

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Всем привет! У меня такой вопрос.На собственном закрытом сайте есть таблица, которую время от времени надо экспортировать в excel. Подскажите какими средствами можно это сделать? Сам сайт работает на Rotor CMS (можно сказать самописец :D) [image: Вот эта таблица]

Comment: Как вариант: https://habr.com/ru/post/245233/

Comment: В этом вопросе приведены некоторые варианты библиотек https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/989437/256824

Comment: Я использую PhpExcel. Пишут, что он устарел, но на старом проекте работает исправно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имел возможность недавно поработать с такой библиотекой как [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) (php)

Если вам нужен простой и быстрый экспорт(импорт) данных в Excel - советую обратить внимание:

1. Spout способен обрабатывать файлы любого размера;
2. Для обработки любого файла, Spout требуется всего 3МБ памяти;
3. API Spout удобен для разработчиков;
4. Потоковый механизм Spout делает его невероятно быстрым.